# Как исправить проблему с PPPOE подключением на Windows 10?

Tags: windows, сеть, windows-10, pppoe

Сервер на Windows 10 имеет 2 сетевые платы,
В первую подключен домашний Ростелеком, по нему нужно подключаться через PPPOE (логин:пароль)
Во второю сетевуху подключена витая пара из Роутера (тот же ростелеком, но уже с доступом к интернету, PPPOE поднят на самом роутере).

В момент подключения PPPOE на сервере - оно рвется через секунду (если подключен провод из роутера).
Если вторая сетевая плата свободна - тогда PPPOE остается работающим.

Как то можно оставить PPPOE стабильным, при подключенной витой паре из роутера?

Нужно это, чтоб было резервное подключение к серверу (помимо PPPOE - на нем белый IP)
Но PPPOE не всегда подключается при перезагрузке.
Поэтому провод из wifi роутера - как резервный канал для подключения к серверу по RDP

Comment: Настроить маршруты?

Comment: @Владимир-Клыков Может быть, по моей ситуации где можно примеры найти? по настройке маршрутов